# Disable emulated scroll wheel (EmulateWheel) for specific programs

Tags: x11, devices, thinkpad

Is it possible to disable evdev's EmulateWheel option when using specific programs? In my use case, I would like to be able to interact with the Acme text editor and with some VMs using my Thinkpad's middle-trackpoint-button as just an ordinary middle button rather than an "EmulateWheelButton".

It would be less convenient, but acceptable, if there were a simple command to turn emulation on and off, so that I could bind this command to a hotkey so I can toggle it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the properties of input devices with the [`xinput`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml) command. See [Make mouse movements scroll when the middle button is held down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down/102011#102011) for a detailed explanation. You'll want something like

```
xinput --set-prop 'Thinkpad Trackpoint' 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' 0
```

where `Thinkpad Trackpoint` is the name of the device found in the output of `xinput list`, and the final value is 0 to turn off and 1 to turn on.

These options cannot be changed based on the active program. A few advanced window managers allow you to run arbitrary program on a focus switch. A few advanced window managers (mostly the same, I expect) would let you program something like EmulateWheel which would only occur on certain windows. I'd expect Fvwm, Sawfish, Awesome and Xmonad to cope (with a nontrivial but not insurmountable amount of coding), and not many more.