# Scrolling with mouse while right button held down

Tags: x11, gnome, mouse, scrolling

I'm trying to configure my mouse to push down a button (right), hold on and drag down/up on a page resulting in scrolling the page like I would do with the wheel.
I found the following question/answer in this forum which exactly describes what I'm looking for:
[Make mouse movements scroll when the middle button is held down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down/102011?newreg=3fc0402faa974b488476b86f23110654)

So, I have a CentOS 6.6 runing in a VM hosted by an VMWare ESXi 5.0.0
Just following the Answer provided by Gilles I found the following output on my CentOS:

```
$ xinput --list
    - Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    -   - Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    -   - ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    -   - Macintosh mouse button emulation          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    - Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        - Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        - Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So the first difference is that I have "ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse" instead of "Generic USB Mouse" what is mentioned in original answer
Then:

```
$ xinput --list-props 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse'
Device 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse':
        Device Enabled (112):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (114): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (232):     0
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (233):       1.000000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (234):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (235):    10.000000
```

So I don't have properties, what are mentioned in original answer to modify them: 
EmulateWheel, EmulateWheelButton

I tried several possibilities like adding in xorg.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wheel Emulation"
    MatchProduct "ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse"
    Option "EmulateWheel" "on"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
    Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

but I'm unable to figure out:
1. why my mouse device 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse' doesn't have those EmulateWheel, EmulateWheelButton X properties
2. if it is possible to configure any other device which have EmulateWheel, EmulateWheelButton X properties so I could continue with settings in original answer