# How to scroll in Eclipse with mouse wheel-button pushed down

Tags: mouse, eclipse, scrolling

I'm looking for plugin in Eclipse which supports scrolling with the wheel-button pushed down and moving the mouse up and down.
The only plugin I found so far is:
https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-mmb-scroller/
but unfortunatelly this one doesn't work for me under Linux.
Is it possible to configure Eclipse or install a plugin which supports this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, actually the mentioned plugin does work under Linux too !!!
I was trying on a hacked Linux, where I disabled the middle button action with:

```
xmodmap -e “pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9”
```

After I found this:
http://eclipse-n-mati.blogspot.com/2009/09/new-plug-in-scrolling-with-middle.html?_sm_au_=iMV6sl6Rnq4nsnTQ
and read trough the comments, it was strange to me why it doesn't work on my Linux :)

So for Eclipse it's solved this... Would be good if I could set this scrolling Linux wide:
 [Scrolling with mouse while right button held down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253413/scrolling-with-mouse-while-right-button-held-down)