# How to change mouse acceleration in X permanently?

Tags: x11, mouse, xinput

I've found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity) about how to change mouse acceleration:

```
xinput --set-prop 14 293 1
```

This works for me. I've tried putting this to my openbox's autostart script, but after some time my mouse ID(and the property ID) changed, and it doesn't work anymore. I don't want to fix the wrong problem - so please, tell me: is there a way to make this change permanent?

Comment: Via a configuration file in [`xorg.conf.d`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#In_Xorg_configuration) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a name instead of a numerical ID. Run `xinput list` to see the available devices and `xinput list-props` to see a device's properties. See [Make mouse movements scroll when the middle button is held down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down/102011#102011) for examples.

Alternatively, if this is your personal machine, you can set this up system-wide by adding a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Again, see [Make mouse movements scroll when the middle button is held down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down/102011#102011) for an example. The `Identifier` clause identifies the stanza in the configuration file, it's the `MatchProduct` clause that identifies the device.