# Mouse auto-scroll (VirtualBox)

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, scrolling, xinput

**Problem**: I am looking to add auto-scrolling--the function of panning a window after pressing the middle-mouse button--to my environment and all user applications. The best solution I've found is enabling `Evdev Wheel Emulation` in `xinput` as detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down). In VirtualBox (guest OS: Fedora 23 stable; host OS: Windows 7), I am unable to find that property.

**Terminal**: [Here](https://gist.github.com/PoliteMaster/95f5a71afb65c95f229c14c9cb32e14e) is all output for `xinput --list-props id`. This is one device:

```
Device 'VirtualBox mouse integration':
Device Enabled (117):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (119): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Calibration Matrix (253):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Calibration Matrix Default (254):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (255):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (256):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (235): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (236):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (237):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (257): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (258): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (259):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (260):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (261):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (262): 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (263): 0
Device Node (238):  "/dev/input/event5"
Device Product ID (239):    33006, 51966
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (264):   <no items>
libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (240):    1
```

**Alternatives**: There are two problems with the `xinput` approach. First, one has to hold the middle-mouse button down (there is no use-as-a-toggle option). Second, windows will line jump instead of scroll smoothly unless there is an application-specific option as in Firefox. If any alternative approaches exist, they would also be answers here.

**Motivation**:
I have always found it more comfortable to use auto-scroll for long pages or hunting and pecking instead of many flicks. Less generally, my mouse wheel is not functioning properly—a documented fault with my model.